How can I byte pack these datastructures in solidity to be more efficient?
I have a bunch of mappings that I want to optimize in my Solidity smart contract, is there a way that I can use byte-packing to reduce the size needed to store all the data in these mappings?
    mapping(address => uint256) internal _deposits; //amount of a token deposited into my contract
    mapping(address => uint256) internal _depositLimits; //max amount allowed to be deposited
    mapping(address => uint256) internal _decimalsCache; //decimals of the erc20 token we are depositing

I believe the _decimalsCache would be a uint8, and for my usecase I'm only storing tokens to 9 units of precision, instead of the typical 18. so _deposits and _depositLimits will always have less than or equal to 9 decimals of precision, or 999999999.999999999 in decimal configuration

SSTORE and SLOAD are the most expensive gas operations the EVM offers. They write and read persistent storage.
mapping assigns a slot in storage. These are an index type that uses a key to determine the location of a 32-byte word to read or write.
Even though the keys are 20-byte addresses, they will treated as 32-byte indexes in the mapping.
Irrespective of the type of variable stored there, they will read and write 32-byte words from those locations, performing any needed type conversion before or after. In other words, 32 bytes is the smallest unit that can be randomly accessed this way.
As it is currently laid out, there are three mappings to three words. If the data can be packed into a struct that fits in one or two words (with loss of precision, of course), then it may be possible to reduce the number of trips to/from storage, which is what you want.
For example:
struct Thing {
  uint8 foo;
  uint32 bar;
}

mapping (address => Thing) thingMap;

That struct fits in one word with room to spare. So, if you are certain that you have no need for higher precision you could, for example, pack 3 or 4 uint64 into a single storage slot, addressable by an address key. You would read and write the entire struct in one move.
Hope it helps.
P.s. please pardon my typos. I'm on a mobile.


Realistically, mapping(address => uint256) internal _deposits; // amount of a token deposited into my contract's 'uint256' type can be replaced with uint64, like mapping(address => uint64) internal _deposits; // amount of a token deposited into my contract. That is because the user's deposit amount will never exceed uint64 bits if you can assure that the value can never exceed 9 decimals, i.e.:

pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Test {
    function getMax64Bits() external pure returns (uint64) {
        return type(uint64).max;
    }
    // 18446744073709551615 <-- that is far more capable than 9 decimals, as you can see
    // 999999999
}


Same as the point №1: you can simply replace mapping(address => uint256) internal _depositLimits; // max amount allowed to be deposited with mapping(address => uint64) internal _depositLimits; // max amount allowed to be deposited, if you're confident that the decimals of the tokens that your contract will accept is capped at utmost 9.
Here you can just do mapping(address => uint8) internal _decimalsCache; // decimals of the erc20 token we are depositing instead, because uint8 can contain values up to 255, so your 2-9 will fit for sure!!

There's no sense in allocating space for uint256 or uint128 values, if at the maximum the amounts will be either less than uint64 or less than uint8.
The final result will look like that:
    mapping(address => uint64) internal _deposits; // amount of a token deposited into my contract
    mapping(address => uint64) internal _depositLimits; // max amount allowed to be deposited
    mapping(address => uint8) internal _decimalsCache; // decimals of the erc20 token we are depositing

